# Query not returning the intended results what am I missing

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an `APEX 5.0 App` that will be used to generate business cards of employees.
I've created a page and `SELECT LIST` page item named (`P1_EMPLOYEE`). It performs this DB query to populate the Select List.

```
select 
    EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME||', '||EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME as FULLNAME,
    EMPLOYEE.SECTION AS SECTION
from 
    EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY 
    EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME asc;
```

and when the page loads it inputs about 900 employees names in the the Select List (ex.. Doe, John, Doe, Jane, etc....).

Also, I have created a BUTTON named (Create) that has a Dynamic Action set to Execute Javascript (ex. `window.open( 'f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&SESSION.:PRINT_REPORT=CreateBizCards' );`).

CreateBizCards above is a Report Query and I've entered the SQL syntax of

```
select 
    EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME as "FIRST NAME",
    EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME as "LAST NAME",
    EMPLOYEE.TITLE as TITLE,
    EMPLOYEE.SECTION as SECTION,
    EMPLOYEE.OFFICE_PHONE as "OFFICE PHONE",
    EMPLOYEE.EMAIL as "E-MAIL"
from 
    EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE
where 
    EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME = :P1_EMPLOYEE;
```

When the (Create) BUTTON is triggered it is suppose to create a report based on the Employee name selected in the `SELECT LIST`.

---

There are two things that are happening that are unwanted results.

First, when the Create button is triggered it will produce a report with a different user with the same last name.

Second, if I alter the SQL Query on the Report Query when the button is triggered it produce a PDF with just the column names and no data.

How should I write a query for the CreateBizCards Report Query so that it will locate the chosen employee from the SELECT LIST on the page item (ex. :P1_EMPLOYEE) and then return the data specific to that employee only?

---

Note: I can't share a APEX URL because this is an internal Application Server.

Comment: And if it wasn't an internal application server you would?  Bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I would with some constraints of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select lists, among others, are items whose LOV expect 1 or 2 columns. Column 1 is the display value, column 2 is the return value.

This is what the "Help" says about using SQL Query for a list-of-values (copied straight from apex 5's help)

> Enter the SQL query definition to populate this list of values.
>   Generally list of value queries are of the form:
>
> ```
> select [displayValue],
>        [returnValue]
>   from ...
>  where ...
>  order by ...
> ```
>
> Each column selected must have a unique name or alias. Oracle
>   recommends using an alias on any column that includes an SQL
>   expression.
>
> **Examples**
>
> **List of values based on SQL query**
>
> ```
> select ename as d, 
>        empno as r
>   from emp 
>  order by 1
> ```
>
> **List of values with same display and return value**
>
> ```
> select ename d,
>        ename r 
>   from emp 
>  order by 1
> ```
>
> Note: When selecting the same column for both the display and return
>   values use a column alias.

---

Your select list item (`P1_EMPLOYEE`) is displaying the concatenation of the employee's `LASTNAME` and `FIRSTNAME`. The item is returning (= its value when referencing its session state) the employee's `SECTION` which I assume is not an employee's last name or is a unique key.

This means that your report query has a where clause that is essentially saying "return the records where a `LASTNAME` is equal to a `SECTION` (`P1_EMPLOYEE`).

I recommend that you set your `P1_ITEM` to something like:

```
Select e.lastname||', '||e.firstname as fullname,
[SOME UNIQUE ID] --replace with primary key
from employee e
order by e.lastname, e.firstname;
```

For your report query you would want to change your where clause to something like this:

```
where e.[SOME UNIQUE ID] = :P1_EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: I added some more info to your answer. It was already quite good and it made no sense to convey exactly the same in another answer as all I had to add was some basic info on the basics.

Comment: Thanks this has been extremely helpful.